# jsPDF working on first save, not updating the pdf on second

Tags: reactjs, pdf, jspdf

Scenario: the user picks a few choices, downloads a PDF. The user then changes a few choices, and downloads a new PDF.

Problem: everything works on the first run, but attempting to download a second PDF gives the user the same, old PDF.

Is there some way to "clear" or "kill" the old PDF? I tried setting the var doc to null before running the function again, and that didn't help. Somehow the first PDF being generated is all I'm able to serve.

Here is the code that makes the PDF. Those frontImg and backImg vars contain the dataURI.

```
$(".button").click(function(){

  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');

  doc.addImage(frontImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
  doc.addPage('a6','l');
  doc.addImage(backImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
  doc.save('file.pdf');

});
```

Anyone have any ideas here? Once the user takes actions that update the frontImg and backImg vars, shouldn't the PDF update too?

Answer (score 0):

you can reset doc variable like first called function. work for me

```
$(".button").click(function(){

  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');

  doc.addImage(frontImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
  doc.addPage('a6','l');
  doc.addImage(backImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
  doc.save('file.pdf');

  doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
});
```